# how to make 1 mini batch out of 3 Keras generators

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN where I have 3 data sources. With other words, I have 3 folders containing images and I need to take 1 image from each folder **in each training step**.

I made the following generator:

```python
def generator_three_imgs(index, batch_size=1):
    anchor_paths = [r'C:\Users\sinthes\Desktop\AI_anaconda\face_recognition\dataset\train\E\Anchor',
                    r'C:\Users\sinthes\Desktop\AI_anaconda\face_recognition\dataset\train\T\Anchor']
    positive_paths = [r'C:\Users\sinthes\Desktop\AI_anaconda\face_recognition\dataset\train\E\Positive',
                      r'C:\Users\sinthes\Desktop\AI_anaconda\face_recognition\dataset\train\T\Positive']
    negative_paths = [r'C:\Users\sinthes\Desktop\AI_anaconda\face_recognition\dataset\train\E\Negative',
                      r'C:\Users\sinthes\Desktop\AI_anaconda\face_recognition\dataset\train\T\Negative']

    generator1 = ImageDataGenerator()
    generator2 = ImageDataGenerator()
    generator3 = ImageDataGenerator()
    anchor_train_batches = generator1.flow_from_directory(anchor_paths[index], target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=batch_size)
    positive_train_batches = generator2.flow_from_directory(positive_paths[index], target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=batch_size)
    negative_train_batches = generator3.flow_from_directory(negative_paths[index], target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=batch_size)
    while True:
        anchor_imgs, anchor_labels = anchor_train_batches.next()
        positive_imgs, positive_labels = positive_train_batches.next()
        negative_imgs, negative_labels = negative_train_batches.next()
        input_imgs = np.append(anchor_imgs, positive_imgs, axis=0)
        input_imgs = np.append(input_imgs, negative_imgs, axis=0)
        labels = np.append(anchor_labels, positive_labels, axis=0)
        labels = np.append(labels, negative_labels, axis=0)
        yield input_imgs, labels
```

So, input_imgs is a (3, 224, 224, 3) dimensional numpy array.
And labels is the array of labels; and in this case there will be 3 labels in the array.

I then try to train it as following:

```python
model.fit_generator(generator_three_imgs(0),
                    steps_per_epoch=23, epochs=1, verbose=2)
```

But it cannot train. The Jupyter notebook crashes by giving the following message:

```python
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

What am I supposed to do here? Is it wrong to try to construct a mini batch which fetches its images from different directories with 3 different Keras generators?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just copy the files into combined folders like the rest of us? You seem to be engineering a solution for a problem that does not need to exist.

Comment: You may be right. I am originally trying to solve a face verification/recognition problem by using triplet loss method. When I train the siamese network, I have 3 input streams (for anchor, positive, negative images). But when I later want to use my model for predictions, I don't have 3 inputs but only 1. The problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558154/how-to-save-restore-make-predictions-with-siamese-network-with-triplet-loss    Would you have any comments on that?

Comment: @edn can't you use a variational autoencoder for facial recognition?

Comment: Would you be able to explain a bit more what variational encoder is?

Comment: @edn it's like a CNN, but this one takes an input and stores a latent before represntion of it. This allows the network to then compare an input to the image it has been trained on and give a score.

Comment: read this “Machine Learning is Fun! Part 4: Modern Face Recognition with Deep Learning” https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78