# Predict unseen data by previously trained model

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am performing supervised machine learning using Scikit-learn. I have two datasets. First dataset contains data that has X features and Y labels. Second dataset contains only X features but NO Y labels. I can successfully perform the LinearSVC for training/testing data and get the Y labels for the test dataset.

Now, I want to use the model that I have trained for the first dataset to predict the second dataset labels. How do I use the pre-trained model from first dataset to second dataset (unseen labels) in Scikit-learn?

**Code snippet from my attempts:**
UPDATED code from comments below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import pandas as pd
import pickle


# ----------- Dataset 1: for training ----------- #
# Sample data ONLY
some_text = ['Books are amazing',
             'Harry potter book is awesome. It rocks',
             'Nutrition is very important',
             'Welcome to library, you can find as many book as you like',
             'Food like brocolli has many advantages']
y_variable = [1,1,0,1,0]

# books = 1 : y label
# food = 0 : y label

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':some_text,
                   'y_variable': y_variable
                          })

# ------------- TFIDF process -------------#
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
features = tfidf.fit_transform(df['text']).toarray()
labels = df.y_variable
features.shape


# ------------- Build Model -------------#
model = LinearSVC()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(features,
                                                 labels,
                                                 train_size=0.5,
                                                 random_state=0)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)


# Export model
pickle.dump(model, open('model.pkl', 'wb'))
# Read the Model
model_pre_trained = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))


# ----------- Dataset 2: UNSEEN DATASET ----------- #

some_text2 = ['Harry potter books are amazing',
             'Gluten free diet is getting popular']

unseen_df = pd.DataFrame({'text':some_text2}) # Notice this doesn't have y_variable. This the is the data set I am trying to predict y_variable labels 1 or 0.


# This is where the ERROR occurs
X_unseen = tfidf.fit_transform(unseen_df['text']).toarray()
y_pred_unseen = model_pre_trained.predict(X_unseen) # error here: 
# ValueError: X has 11 features per sample; expecting 26


print(X_unseen.shape) # prints (2, 11)
print(X_train.shape) # prints (2, 26)


# Looking for an output like this for UNSEEN data
# Looking for results after predicting unseen and no label data. 
text                                   y_variable
Harry potter books are amazing         1
Gluten free diet is getting popular    0
```

It doesn't have to be pickle code as I tried above. I am looking if someone has suggestion or if there is any pre-build function that does the prediction from scikit?

Comment: X_unseen has to have the same features in the same order as X_train and X_test

Comment: We train models, not datasets (edited title); and question has obviously nothing to do with `tensorflow` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see, your first `tfidf` is turning your input into 26 features, while your second `tfidf` is turning them into 11 features. The error is therefore happening because `X_train` is different in shape to `X_unseen`. The prompt tells you that each observation in `X_unseen` has less features than the number of features `model` was trained to receive.

Once you load `model` in the second script, you are fitting another vectorizer to the text. That is, `tfidf` from the first script and `tfidf` from the second one are different objects. In order to make predictions with `model`, you need to transform `X_unseen` using the original `tfidf`. In order to do this, you must export the original vectorizer, load it in the new script and transform the new data with it before passing it to `model`.

```py
### Do this in the first program
# Dump model and tfidf
pickle.dump(model, open('model.pkl', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(tfidf, open('tfidf.pkl', 'wb'))

### Do this in the second program
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
tfidf = pickle.load(open('tfidf.pkl', 'rb'))

# Use `transform` instead of `fit_transform`
X_unseen = tfidf.transform(unseen_df['text']).toarray()

# Predict on `X_unseen`
y_pred_unseen = model_pre_trained.predict(X_unseen)
```

Comment: I see. So, is there a way to predict the 'Unseen' data from the model I have trained? I have same X features in both the datasets.

Comment: Can you update the question by adding a sample of `X_train` and `X_unseen`? It is probably a reshape issue then.

Comment: I updated my answer. This was happening because you fit a brand new `tfidf` on the unseen data and this object was incompatible with `model`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the explanation it makes more sense to me now. I tried your solution above to fit the sample data above, it is working great. However, I use this in my real data set, I am getting error `NotFittedError: The TF-IDF vectorizer is not fitted` for the unseen

Comment: Glad to help! (;

Regarding your error, you have to fit the vectorizer on the training data and then use the fitted vectorizer on the testing data. So you should always use `fit_transform` the first time and only `transform` for later iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you trained an AI to recognize a plane using pictures of the motors, wheels, wings and of the pilot's bowtie. Now you're calling this same AI and you ask it to predict the model of a plane with the bowtie alone. That's what scikit-learn is telling you : there are much less features (= columns) in `X_unseen` than in `X_train` or `X_test`.

Answer (score 0):

ignore the second dataset and use train_test_split to create your test set.